# how to parse data from Soap envelope object in android

Tags: android, soap

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject root = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("InfraWiseDetails");
SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals.getProperty("VisitInfraDetails");

for (int i = 0; i < s_deals_1.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    Object property = s_deals_1.getProperty(i);

    if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
        SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;
        String x = category_list.getProperty("Feedback").toString();
        String y = category_list.getProperty("InfraName").toString();
        String z = category_list.getProperty("Problem").toString();
    }
}
```

this is my Code

in `SoapObject SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();` i am getting response --->

```
anyType{InfraWiseDetails=anyType{VisitInfraDetails=anyType{Feedback=Status OK; InfraName=Tables and Chairs; Problem=null; ResolutionStatus=false; Status=true; };

VisitInfraDetails=anyType{Feedback=Water Quality very poor; InfraName=Water; Problem=Rust in Water; ResolutionStatus=false; Status=false; }; }; VisitMasterId=1; }
```

I want to Parse data from given SoapObject and get all value of FeedBack, Infraname, Problem... **please tell me where am doing wrong i am unable to get value**

Comment: Try this one : SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; and let me know.

Comment: @sanatshukla  SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals
      .getProperty("VisitInfraDetails");

    for (int i = 0; i < s_deals_1.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
     Object property = s_deals_1.getProperty(i);
     String staus = s_deals_1.getProperty(0).toString();
     String InfraName = s_deals_1.getProperty(1).toString();
     String Problem = s_deals_1.getProperty(2).toString();
     String ResolutionStatus = s_deals_1.getProperty(3)
       .toString();
     String Status = s_deals_1.getProperty(4).toString();

    } using this code i am getting only one part value how to ge another one

Comment: @sanatshukla can i send my updated code on paste please i am stucking in some thing

Comment: Iterate your loop on s_deals not on s_deals_1 and get VisitInfraDetails into the loop

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: Accept as correct answer if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long time i am looking on ksoap2 code. Try this :

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject root = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("InfraWiseDetails");

for (int i = 0; i < s_deals.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals.getProperty(i);
    String x = s_deals_1.getProperty("Feedback").toString();
    String y = s_deals_1.getProperty("InfraName").toString();
    String z = s_deals_1.getProperty("Problem").toString();   
}
```

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/cY2Y7Z5KxG3M4HKMQuc69h  this exception is coming please check where am doing worng

Comment: put your code there i need to check code also because error occur on this line MainActivity.java:153

Comment: Object property1 = s_deals.getProperty(0);

    Object property2 = s_deals.getProperty(1);

    SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals
      .getProperty("VisitInfraDetails");
    Problem = s_deals_1.getProperty(2).toString();  i am getting in Bothe Object1 Propert1 and Property2 2 Object can u please tell me how to get Value from these  VisitInfraDetails=anyType{Feedback=null; InfraName=Tables & Chairs; Problem=2 Chairs Broken; ResolutionStatus=false; Status=false; };  getting respone like this

Comment: i am getting object1:  anyType{Feedback=null; InfraName=Tables & Chairs; Problem=2 Chairs Broken; ResolutionStatus=false; Status=false; }  
object2:  anyType{Feedback=null; InfraName=Water; Problem=null; ResolutionStatus=false; Status=false; }   like this way i want to get value from Object base like from object seprate value and object 2 seprate vlaue of  FeedBack an all please suggest me where am doing wrong @sanat shukla

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your Code , You can parse the data from KSoap

`getdata(String SearchValue)`- Call this method inside your do inBackground

```
public void getdata(String SearchValue) 
        {
            // Create request
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);



            PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi4.setName("City");
            pi4.setValue(SearchValue);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
            pi4.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi4);

            // Create envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // Set output SOAP object
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            // Create HTTP call object
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);

            try {
                // Invole web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
                // Get the response
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                //Converting string to Array list
                  ArrayList<String> Servciecityname_arr= new ArrayList<String>();


                if ((response.toString()).contains("{")) 
                {

                    SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);


                           Cityname = jb.getString("CityName123");


                           Servciecityname_arr.add(Cityname);

                    }

                    CITYNAME = new String[Servciecityname_arr.size()];
                    CITYNAME = Servciecityname_arr.toArray(CITYNAME);


                } 
                else
                {
                    Status_Response = response.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "Error in catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```